# ESCAPED double quotes cause Database Error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a TEXT field in my phpMyAdmin database which is filled with a JSON encoded string

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

the string in the Database looks like this:
`..."p_name":"hello (world\" / 000\")","p_value":"200"...`

I'm trying to find it like this

```
$name = "hello (world" / 000")"
$search = '%\"p_name\":\"'.$name.'\"%';
$results = $this->getByWhere('textfield LIKE"' . $search . '" ');
```

I always get an database error, also when I escape the quotes in the $name variable.
So basically I need a query to find that specific string. hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste the error .... will help.. on side-note if you are using mysql then insted of TEXT you can use JSON as type for column... it will make working with json easier..

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing mysql/mariadb databases. Your application is connecting directly to the database and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/ 000")\"%" ' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE textfield LIKE"%\"p_name\":\"hello (world" / 000")\"%"

Comment: You have an unescaped string! _$name = "hello (world **"** / 000")"_ Should be $name = "hello (world \" / 000\")"